# Python str() - specify which kind of quotes to add/use?

Tags: python, string

Is there a way to influence the kind of quotes that python uses when casting a tuple/list to string?

For some NLP software I get tuples somewhat like this:

```
("It", ("isn't", "true"))
```

I want to cast it to a string and simply remove all double quotes and commas:

```
(It (Isn't true))
```

However, python is having its way with the quotes, it seems to prefer single quotes:

```
>>> print str(("It", ("Isn't" ,"true")))
('It', ("Isn't", 'true'))
```

, making my life more difficult. Of course I could write my own function for printing it out part-by-part, but there is so much similarity between the representation and native python tuples.

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to accomplish? Is this strictly for display purposes?

Comment: Nope, the output has to have a certain syntax: without double quotes, with single quotes only used as in my example, with parens to indicate grouping, with spaces to separate words. Then another program can read it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't rely on the exact representation that repr uses. I'd just do as you thought and write your own function -- I don't see it being more than a handful of lines of code. This should get you going.

```
def s_exp(x):
    if isinstance(x, (tuple, list)):
        return '(%s)' % (' '.join(map(s_exp, x)))
    return str(x)
```

Writing your own function may be inevitable: if your strings contain brackets "(", ")" or spaces " " then you'll need some form of escaping to produce well-formed s-expressions.

Comment: Ok, the general opinion seems to be that the answer is "no". Your bit of code convinced me that it isn't hard to do it manually. Actually, it's fewer lines than a couple of `str.replace()`'s.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use json instead

```
>>> import json
>>> print json.dumps(("It", ("isn't", "true")))
["It", ["isn't", "true"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python objects have a `__str__` method that converts them into a string representation. This is what does the conversion and it's intelligent enough to use one kind of quote when the other is used in the string and also to do escaping if both are used.

In your example, the `It` got single quoted since that's what Python "prefers". The double quote was used for `Isn't` since it contains a `.

You should roll out your own converter really. Using a little recursion, it should be quite small.

Comment: str() applied to a tuple calls repr() on the elements of the tuple, so `__repr__` is the relevant method and not `__str__` in this case.

Comment: `str` when applied to a function tries to get at the `__str__` method and if it can't find one, uses the `__repr__` method. Overriding `__repr__` is probably not a good idea since it has a specific purpose (programmer representation). He wants a string representation so `__str__` is the method to go after. However, you cannot edit methods of builtins so a new class type derived from tuple or a custom formatter function are the options available. I'd go with the latter.

Comment: If you override `__str__` on a class and then try str((a, b, c)) where a, b and c are of your class you'll find it doesn't work -- repr() and not str() gets called. You can test this by trying `str(('a',))` which produces "('a',)" and not "(a,)" which it would if str() was being used for the tuple elements.

Comment: You're correct. I misread what you wrote. *elements* of a tuple will be printed using the repr. It's the object itself that will be printed the way I mentioned in my comment. Either way, the fact that you cannot override the `__repr__` or the `__str_` of a builtin type makes this a moot point.